# percona server listens to 2 ports after changing port number from 3306 to 4470

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, port, percona

I have installed percona server in an Ubuntu server 12.04 running as a Virtual Machine and copied

```
/usr/share/mysql/my-small.cnf #to
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

I restarted the server `sudo service mysql restart` and did some checks on the netstat level to see the listening port for msyqld process.

```
tcp 0 0.0.0.0:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 9800/mysqld
unix 2 [ACC] STREAM LISTENING 21771 9800/mysqld /var/run/msyqld/mysqld.sock
```

I have then edited the configuration file to listen to the port 4470 instead and restarted again mysql. I could login with both 3306 and 4470. below is the command I use.

```
msyql -uroot -p -P4470 // login successful after password challenge
mysql -uroot -p // login successful after password challenge
```

checking the help also brings the port 4470 forth.

```
mysql --help | grep port
-P, --port =# Portnumber to use for connection or 0 for default to, in --- 
port 4470
```

I am totally confused as to what is happening. Can anybody shed some light?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exactly same issue...
What happen is, there are 2 settings in my.cnf for port: Client and Mysqld.
You have to change the port in both configurations:

```
[client]
port        = <CustomPort>

[mysqld]
port        = <CustomPort>
```